# Shopify - Create a form with pure HTML

Tags: shopify

Im new to shopify and i have a question about forms.

There is a custom contact form in the theme. But on another page i wish to have a contact form with much more inputs. Before i start building anything. Is it possible to just **create a form** with the **HTML block**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This documentation might help you:
https://shopify.dev/themes/customer-engagement/add-contact-form

Please check optional inputs part to get more info on how to add custom inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you need to create a template file  and this template you can call in cms pages in Shopify I think it's helpful for  you
I'm also new here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).